# Выборка из БД по дате в разных форматах

Tags: mysql, sql

Понадобилось мне извлечь некоторые данные из Excel.
Сконвертировал в CSV, импортировал в MySQL.

Нужно выбрать все строки с условием по дате.
Поле date - тип `varchar` (при импорте все поля `varchar`).
Дата хранится в нескольких форматах:

```
06.08.1948

06/10/1957

05/02/87
```

Порядок вроде как не нарушен, то есть "**число - месяц - год**".
Каждая запись это человек.

Нужно выбрать всех людей которым на сегодняшнее число есть 18 лет.

Comment: *Поле date - тип varchar* - что мешает хранить данные в правильном формате, вместо того, чтобы делать велосипед ?

Comment: Таблица экспортировалась из csv файла. Выбрать тип столбцов невозможно. Сделал выборку так `SELECT * FROM register WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 973209600`

Answer (score 1):

Можно несколько раз применить `STR_TO_DATE` с разным форматом даты:

```
SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y') AS d1, STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m.%d.%Y') AS d2
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "06.08.1948" AS dt
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS id, "06/10/1957" AS dt
    UNION 
    SELECT 3 AS id, "05/02/87" AS dt
) AS t1;
```

Получаем:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | d1         | d2         |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | NULL       | 1948-06-08 |
|  2 | 1957-06-10 | NULL       |
|  3 | 1987-05-02 | NULL       |
+----+------------+------------+
```

---

Затем выбираем нужный формат:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(d1, d2) AS dt
FROM (
    SELECT id, STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y') AS d1, STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m.%d.%Y') AS d2
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS id, "06.08.1948" AS dt
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS id, "06/10/1957" AS dt
        UNION 
        SELECT 3 AS id, "05/02/87" AS dt
    ) AS t1
) AS t2
```

Вариант выше был для лучшего понимания. Вот более короткая запись:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(dt, '%m.%d.%Y')) AS dt
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, "06.08.1948" AS dt
    UNION 
    SELECT 2 AS id, "06/10/1957" AS dt
    UNION 
    SELECT 3 AS id, "05/02/87" AS dt
) AS t1;
```

Результат:

```
+----+------------+
| id | dt         |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 1948-06-08 |
|  2 | 1957-06-10 |
|  3 | 1987-05-02 |
+----+------------+
```

---

Для фильтрации по возрасту в конце добавьте такую строку:

```
HAVING ((YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(dt)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(dt,5))) >= 40
```

Она находит возраст по разности годов текущего и в записи, а также вылетает 1 год, если текущие месяц-день меньше месяца-дня в записи. 40 замените на 18 (использовал для наглядности на текущих данных)

---

Форматы дат можете добавить или поменять на нужные Вам.

Вообще, если таблица очень большая или подобные задачи встречаются часто, то советую посмотреть в сторону [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) – там такие операции можно проворачивать значительно проще, притом работая напрямую с CSV или XLS.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), 
         STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) as date
FROM test
WHERE
  (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NOT NULL AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= CURDATE() ) OR  
  (STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL AND 
 DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= CURDATE())
```

[Тест](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eh3AHdLk8yCbJ1AqrL2dgQ/1)

[Документация по STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

[Документация по DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

---

**Тест**

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  date VARCHAR (200)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (1, '06.08.1948');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (2, '06.08.2002');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (3, '06.08.2003');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (4, '06/10/1957');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (5, '05/02/87');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (6, '05/02/88');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (7, '05/01/00');
INSERT INTO test (id, date) VALUES (8, '05/02/21');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
id,
IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y')) as date
FROM test
WHERE
(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') IS NOT NULL AND
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= CURDATE() ) OR  
(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') IS NOT NULL AND 
 DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) <= CURDATE());

| id  | date       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1948-08-06 |
| 4   | 1957-10-06 |
| 5   | 1987-02-05 |
| 6   | 1988-02-05 |
| 7   | 2000-01-05 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eh3AHdLk8yCbJ1AqrL2dgQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже указали в комментариях наиболее простым и правильным вариантом будет хранение данных с правильным типом данных (DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP) на стороне MySQL DB. @AivanF уже посоветовал использовать Pandas в своем ответе.

Вот небольшой рабочий пример на Python (доп. модули: pandas, pymysql, sqlalchemy), который читает данные из Excel файла, конвертирует тип столбца `dt` в `datetime` и сохраняет в таблицу MySQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine    # pip install sqlalchemy
import pymysql                          # pip install PyMySQL
import pandas as pd                     # pip install pandas

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

df = pd.read_excel(r'd:\temp\file.xlsx')

df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], dayfirst=True)
df.to_sql('my_table', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

---

Пример преобразования типа данных в Pandas с разными форматами данных.

Исходный DataFrame (в таком виде мы прочитали данные из Excel/CSV):

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   id          dt
0   1  06.08.1948
1   2  06/10/1957
2   3    05/30/87
3   4  2018-11-03
4   5      8.3.03
```

после преобразования:

```
In [13]: df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], dayfirst=True)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   id         dt
0   1 1948-08-06
1   2 1957-10-06
2   3 1987-05-30
3   4 2018-11-03
4   5 2003-03-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант и если к столбцу `date` нет ключей:

```
UPDATE test SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d.%m.%Y') WHERE substring(date,3,1) = '.';
UPDATE test SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') WHERE substring(date,3,1) = '/';
```

после чего Вы сможете изменить тип столбца `date` на `DATE` и в дальнейшем не усложнять себе жизнь.

P.S.: либо создайте новый столбец `date2` с типом `DATE` и делайте `update` в него, после чего удалите старый столбец `date` и измените имя столбца `date2` на `date`.